# How to fetch data from node js with codeigniter's model?

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter

UPDATED. 
I'm using codeigniter and i want to fetch data from node js api but i need to be able to get it by codeigniter's models, i also need to be able to pass parameters to node js.

Here is what i've done so far - it's working fine - but i can't figure how to pass parameter to the SQL query - from the model to node js.

If it's not clear up to now - please review the code - i added some explanations there also.

**And here is the model (users_model.php)**

```
  public function node_get($id) 
{
    $foo = file_get_contents('http://localhost:3000/'.$id);
    return $foo ;
}
```

**Here the node.js app (app.js)**

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "something",
user: "something",
password: "something",
database: "something"
});

  var user_id; <---------------------------How can i pass this in the model?

  var user_data;
  con.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM users_data WHERE user_id ="+user_id, function 
    (err, 
    result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    user_data = result;
    // console.log(user_data);
      });
   });


   app.get('/', function(req, res){

   res.send(JSON.stringify(user_data, null, 3));

   });


  app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Have you set second connection credentials in `APPPATH.'database.php'`? What is the error you are facing? Don't post _rough sketch_ but post exact code you are using that doesn't work along with error you are getting. Check here [how to ask](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) expecting most valuable answers. Help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks - since i don't know how it can be done - i don't have  errors or some code that i can post... i just need a explanation of how to use node js with codeigniter models

Comment: Then you need to try harder with explaining/showing what you have so far and in what point of your work problem occurred. What are _real time features_? I (neither anyone can't pull words from you if you don't want to share) But question is still unclear since we don't know how exactly to help you. If you are using `nodejs` there is some node js server side code and some front side JS. Show it what is there. If there is no code at all, start writing some and if you face issue, post exact problem tied to code you've written. That is how SoF works.

Comment: Ok, i'll do some testings and i'll update the question - thanks

Comment: Tpojka  I've update the question - you are welcome the check it out - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it....

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var helmet = require('helmet');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var mysql = require('mysql');

app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());
app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
app.use(helmet.frameguard);
app.get('/:user_id', function(req, res){

var user_id = req.params.user_id;

if(user_id == null){
    user_id =1;
}
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "something",
    user: "something",
    password: "something",
    database: "something"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT * FROM users_data WHERE user_id ="+user_id, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send( JSON.stringify(result));
    });
});

});

app.listen(port);
```